# Sending an email

Tags: php, html

Using PHP, I am trying to email details from a form.

I am getting a confirmation message on my page that the email has been sent, but I never receive the message in my inbox.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: you MUST show what you have so far if you expect any help.

Comment: Specify your problem by adding the related code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!Your efforts are not shown in your question,give some code and are you using localhost

Comment: your question is not constructive

Answer (score 3):

If your are using gmail other a similar webmail service its highly likely that your email got treaten as spam.

Comment: @Shylux That's not true. And I guess as every beginner he is playing with localhost, so he doesn't have a mail server.

Comment: @ltehnological There are several mail api's which you can use. I mad the experience that my mail got treated as spam as i forgot to set the title. But i think you are right. He seems to be a beginner.