# Email sent from form is not delivered to recipient

Tags: php, html, css, email

I made a php form but I have a problem. The form is sending the message and a thank message displays but am not receiving the message in my gmail inbox.

Comment: and where is your not-working code....you should post that too

Comment: Considering your post got closed yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613865/sending-an-email), I would think that you would have figured out that **you need to provide more detail!**

Comment: var_dump() your mail function

Comment: Why are people +1'ing this?  This question is the equivalent of "I wrote a letter and stuck it in an envelope, but why didn't my friend get it?"  There's a million things that could go wrong, no details are provided, no effort is shown is to debug the problem, and it's a duplicate.

Comment: Please include where your testing this script, locally or on production, windows or linux? and check your server mail log. Is all fair and well telling us your story but without more info  or your code that sends it could be lots of things.

Answer (score 1):

Check your server mail log. Check your Gmail junk folder.

Answer (score 1):

Well post the code! I've used [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)'s mail function and it worked. Perhaps Gmail is filtering the e-mail sent by PHP. Try using an e-mail account on a different domain to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: it is a known problem that gmail blocks most PHP mails, or puts them in the spam folder.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail may be treating the e-mail as spam. Try sending to an e-mail account not on Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of hundreds of problems, many of which are beyond your control.

I had a similar problem trying to make a simple PHP app to send email - one day it worked, the next day it didn't. No error. No indication that it failed. Nothing.

To debug the problem I installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine which meant I had my own web abd mail servers to play with - made it easy to check server side logs and multiple recipients etc. Basically you are in 100% control - if it works in this environment but not in the real world, chances are it isn't your fault!

Turned out that my web host had put in new security policies that the "From:" address had to be a physical mailbox on their system. Not my hosting user name. Not a forwarded web address.
- they just didn't bother to tell anyone they had done it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your to and from set correctly. If the from is not an address gmail likes then it could be taken as spam.